# registerForDraggedTypes with custom file formats

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Developer Documentations doesn't provides fully describe of registerForDraggedTypes method. For example, i want that my app allow access only "*.abc" files. How can i do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you'd like to have files dragged onto your view, your should register for the `NSFilenamesPboardType` type.  If you want accept only certain filenames, you can do that in your implementation of `performDragOperation:`.  Something like:

```
- (BOOL)performDragOperation:(id < NSDraggingInfo >)sender {
    NSArray *draggedFilenames = [[sender draggingPasteboard] propertyListForType:NSFilenamesPboardType];
    if ([[[draggedFilenames objectAtIndex:0] pathExtension] isEqual:@"abc"])
        return YES;
    else
        return NO;
}
```

Comment: Looking only at the first path is bad practice, as it makes for inconsistent behavior when the user drags multiple files. If the first one is a .abc file, you return `YES` regardless of whether any others are; conversely, if the first one is not a .abc file, you return `NO` even if there is a .abc file among the other files. Also, you're comparing case-sensitively; you won't match .ABC files, for example. Better would be to loop through the `pathExtension` s and use `caseInsensitiveCompare:` to find .abc files (and decide whether you want to return `YES` if any non-.abc files are in the drag).

Comment: Yep.  It's also a bad idea to use path extensions to decide which files to handle; better to use Uniform Type Identifiers.  This snippet is just a starting point.