# What is the path to the Mac OSX application Contents folder

Tags: objective-c++

I am writing an Objective-c++ application and I am trying to reach the applications `Contents` folder.

Let's pretend my apps name is MyApp.app. If I run my application from Xcode then I can reach the `Contents` folder like this:

```
std::fstream file;
file.open("MyApp.app/Contents/some_text_file.txt");
if(file.is_open()) {
...
}
else {
...
}
```

But If I run my built application without Xcode, then `file.is_open()` fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]` will give you the path of the `MyApp.app` directory. You can then add `Contents` to that path.

Alternatively, `[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]` will give you the path to the `MyApp.app/Contents/Resources` directory. You can then remove the subdirectory from that path; see [Working with paths from [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949992/working-with-paths-from-nsbundle-mainbundle-resourcepath)

Answer (score 2):

Use [NSBundle](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class to get informations on your application bundle.
[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] give you full path to MyApp.app.