# Open image file only when dragging to application icon

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm working on a small app that works with image (it is not a document based app).
I want to be able to open image files by dragging them to the app icon.
I have looked at this very clear explanation

[Cocoa/Obj-C - Open file when dragging it to application icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5331774/cocoa-obj-c-open-file-when-dragging-it-to-application-icon)

and have added the ability to open .png files by dragging to the app icon.

Do I have to add ALL the file types I require separately , or is there a way to specify ALL image types (for instance all image types that an NSImageView will accept)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your application’s Info.plist’s, you can specify the [Uniform Type Identifier](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/UniformTypeIdentifier.html) `public.image` in `LSItemContentTypes` for a document type even if your application is not document-based:

```
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.image</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

or

[image: public.image UTI]

If you’re opening other types of files as well, you may want to check whether the dropped file is an image:

```
- (BOOL)application:(NSApplication *)sender openFile:(NSString *)filename {
    NSError *error;
    NSString *fileUTI = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] typeOfFile:filename error:&error];

    if (!fileUTI)
        NSLog(@"Error when trying to detect the type of file %@: %@", filename, error);
    else if (UTTypeConformsTo((__bridge CFStringRef)fileUTI, kUTTypeImage))
        NSLog(@"%@ is an image", filename);
    else
        NSLog(@"%@ is not an image", filename);

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was after, and +1 for the additional check in the openFile method.